# how to detect CD physically inserted into drive

Tags: linux, udev, data-cd, ioctl

How to detect that CD was physically inserted into CD mechanics ASAP?
The CD is mounted automatically but it takes like 20 seconds sometimes - and it is just then that I know the CD is inserted.. nothing seems to notify me beforehand.

I would be happy with 1 sec after insertion of CD to know that its physically there(I dont care if its mounted or not).

I tried `blkid /dev/sr0` which shall return special value when CD is inserted.. but this blocks until CD is mounted.

Then I tried ioctl like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652520/how-to-check-if-cd-drive-is-open-or-closed-in-linux) but it returns CDS_NO_DISC and then only CDS_DISC_OK after CD is mounted (after 20 seconds)

Is there maybe some file in /sys /proc or somewhere that the CD is inserted?

I am on embedded Linux.. but I think it doesnt matter - I am running kernel 4.1.18

UPDATE:

we already use udev rule for mounting.. but triggering this udev is just a little faster (2-3 seconds faster, but still more than 10-15 secs) than checking mounted CD..
This is the rule:

```
KERNEL=="sr*", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1", GOTO="automount_end"
```

Comment: You hardly would get sustained 1 sec mount time: even the disk that is visually just fine could be read with errors and this makes the device to try different speeds until it get it read or report failure.

Comment: @Serge I do not want the CD to be mounted after 1sec.. I just want to know that it was inserted.. I will update question as its not very clear..

Comment: Are you sure it takes 20 seconds to mount? If you insert (for example) a USB stick, does that take 20 seconds to mount too?  My guess is that the drives takes nearly 20 seconds to recognise the disk and inform your OS that it's ready.

Comment: @garethTheRed ok.. I tested this (on normal PC) - it takes 9 seconds to autorecognize that CD is there and mount.. the mounting itself is like 3 seconds.. I tested USB on embedded device - it takes only 4-5 secs to automount plugged USB - I wonder whats wrong there.. anyway there must be something (maybe in kernel) that could notify me that the CD is inserted..

Comment: Your normal PC doesn't have the same CD drive as the one in question?  Just a thought. `udev` detects device insertions - have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/359855/how-to-detect-insertion-of-dvd-disc

Comment: @garethTheRed I just found out that we already use udev script for mounting (and we use the correct faster "change" type).. but this udev is only little faster than mount itself.. but thanks for interesting link :)